# Fault Tolerant MD5 calculation for large files in C#

Tags: .net, md5

Is there any way to do the incremental md5 calculation of large files but at each nth step save the read position and md5 state data such when the process fails or a network/IO happens, then it can be restarted from the last known good position in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do this with the [built-in MD5](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/md5.cs,c7a9f849977ccfaa) class.  There is no way to retrieve and restore state data.  The existing [HashAlgorithm.State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.state(v=vs.110).aspx) field appears to be used for sanity-checking the hash operation.

I don't see a way to do this with the [Microsoft Crypto API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380256(v=vs.85).aspx), either, but I could be wrong.

It's almost always better to use someone else's well-tested security code.  In this case, I don't know of any implementations that would be able to serialize an internal state.

I think you could write your own MD5 class for this.  See the [MD5 specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt).  The internal state involved is very small compared to the size of the input.  It would be possible to expose this state as some kind of opaque object that the caller could persist and restore it later.

Comment: Instead of rolling your own you would be likely better off finding a 3rd party library that implemented it in managed code in a class that was marked `[Serializeable]`. Less likely for errors. Still +1

Comment: Thanks. I added my solution in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution to the problem and unit test to show proof of concept.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using SInnovations.Azure.Storage.MD5;
namespace Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {

            var md5 = new MD5Managed();
            MD5Managed md5state = null;

            var bytes = new byte[1024 * 8];
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\test\c2474dab-f209-4a7c-8ed4-b7ba71c5b799.zip"))
            {
                var i = new Random().Next(0, (int)stream.Length / bytes.Length);
                while (stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length) != 0)
                {
                    md5.TransformBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, null, 0);

                    if (!(i-- > 0))
                    {
                        if (md5state == null)
                        {
                            md5state = new MD5Managed();
                            var state = md5.GetState();
                            md5state.LoadState(state);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            md5state.TransformBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, null, 0);
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

            md5.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, 0);
            md5state.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, 0);

            string md5Hash = GetMDHASH(md5);
            string md5HashStated = GetMDHASH(md5state);

            Assert.AreEqual(md5Hash, md5HashStated);
            Console.WriteLine(md5Hash);

        }

        private static string GetMDHASH(MD5Managed md5)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte b in md5.Hash)
            {
                s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
            }
            var md5Hash = s.ToString();
            return md5Hash;
        }
    }
}
```

and md5 hash algorithm

```
namespace SInnovations.Azure.Storage.MD5
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Linq;

    /// <summary>
    /// MD5Managed: A HashAlgorithm implementation that acts as a thin wrapper
    /// around a C# translation of the MD5 reference implementation. The C code
    /// has been translated as closely as possible so that most of the original
    /// structure remains and comparisons between the two are straightforward.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Derived from the RSA Data Security, Inc. MD5 Message-Digest Algorithm.
    /// 
    /// Specification:
    /// RFC1321 - The MD5 Message-Digest Algorithm
    /// http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1321.html
    /// 
    /// Original license:
    /// Copyright (C) 1991-2, RSA Data Security, Inc. Created 1991. All
    /// rights reserved.
    /// 
    /// License to copy and use this software is granted provided that it
    /// is identified as the "RSA Data Security, Inc. MD5 Message-Digest
    /// Algorithm" in all material mentioning or referencing this software
    /// or this function.
    /// 
    /// License is also granted to make and use derivative works provided
    /// that such works are identified as "derived from the RSA Data
    /// Security, Inc. MD5 Message-Digest Algorithm" in all material
    /// mentioning or referencing the derived work.
    /// 
    /// RSA Data Security, Inc. makes no representations concerning either
    /// the merchantability of this software or the suitability of this
    /// software for any particular purpose. It is provided "as is"
    /// without express or implied warranty of any kind.
    /// 
    /// These notices must be retained in any copies of any part of this
    /// documentation and/or software.
    /// </remarks>
    public class MD5Managed : HashAlgorithm
    {
        // Current context
        private readonly MD5_CTX _context = new MD5_CTX();
        // Last hash result
        private readonly byte[] _digest = new byte[16];
        // True if HashCore has been called
        private bool _hashCoreCalled;
        // True if HashFinal has been called
        private bool _hashFinalCalled;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance.
        /// </summary>
        public MD5Managed()
        {
            InitializeVariables();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes internal state.
        /// </summary>
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            InitializeVariables();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes variables.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeVariables()
        {
            MD5Init(_context);
            _hashCoreCalled = false;
            _hashFinalCalled = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the hash code with the data provided.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="array">Data to hash.</param>
        /// <param name="ibStart">Start position.</param>
        /// <param name="cbSize">Number of bytes.</param>
        protected override void HashCore(byte[] array, int ibStart, int cbSize)
        {
            if (null == array)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
            }

            if (_hashFinalCalled)
            {
                throw new CryptographicException("Hash not valid for use in specified state.");
            }
            _hashCoreCalled = true;

            MD5Update(_context, array, (uint)ibStart, (uint)cbSize);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finalizes the hash code and returns it.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected override byte[] HashFinal()
        {
            _hashFinalCalled = true;
            MD5Final(_digest, _context);
            return Hash;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the hash as an array of bytes.
        /// </summary>
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1065:DoNotRaiseExceptionsInUnexpectedLocations", Justification = "Matching .NET behavior by throwing here.")]
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2201:DoNotRaiseReservedExceptionTypes", Justification = "Matching .NET behavior by throwing NullReferenceException.")]
        public override byte[] Hash
        {
            get
            {
                if (!_hashCoreCalled)
                {
                    throw new NullReferenceException();
                }
                if (!_hashFinalCalled)
                {
                    // Note: Not CryptographicUnexpectedOperationException because that can't be instantiated on Silverlight 4
                    throw new CryptographicException("Hash must be finalized before the hash value is retrieved.");
                }

                return _digest;
            }
        }

        // Return size of hash in bits.
        public override int HashSize
        {
            get
            {
                return _digest.Length * 8;
            }
        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        // MD5 reference implementation begins here. //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////

        /* MD5 context. */
        private class MD5_CTX
        {
            public readonly uint[] state;   /* state (ABCD) */
            public readonly uint[] count;   /* number of bits, modulo 2^64 (lsb first) */
            public readonly byte[] buffer;  /* input buffer */

            public MD5_CTX()
            {
                state = new uint[4];
                count = new uint[2];
                buffer = new byte[64];
            }

            public void Clear()
            {
                Array.Clear(state, 0, state.Length);
                Array.Clear(count, 0, count.Length);
                Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }

        /* Constants for MD5Transform routine. */
        private const int S11 = 7;
        private const int S12 = 12;
        private const int S13 = 17;
        private const int S14 = 22;
        private const int S21 = 5;
        private const int S22 = 9;
        private const int S23 = 14;
        private const int S24 = 20;
        private const int S31 = 4;
        private const int S32 = 11;
        private const int S33 = 16;
        private const int S34 = 23;
        private const int S41 = 6;
        private const int S42 = 10;
        private const int S43 = 15;
        private const int S44 = 21;

        private static byte[] PADDING;

        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1810:InitializeReferenceTypeStaticFieldsInline", Justification = "More compact this way")]
        static MD5Managed()
        {
            PADDING = new byte[64];
            PADDING[0] = 0x80;
        }

        /* F, G, H and I are basic MD5 functions. */
        private static uint F(uint x, uint y, uint z) { return (((x) & (y)) | ((~x) & (z))); }
        private static uint G(uint x, uint y, uint z) { return (((x) & (z)) | ((y) & (~z))); }
        private static uint H(uint x, uint y, uint z) { return ((x) ^ (y) ^ (z)); }
        private static uint I(uint x, uint y, uint z) { return ((y) ^ ((x) | (~z))); }

        /* ROTATE_LEFT rotates x left n bits. */
        private static uint ROTATE_LEFT(uint x, int n) { return (((x) << (n)) | ((x) >> (32 - (n)))); }

        /* FF, GG, HH, and II transformations for rounds 1, 2, 3, and 4.
           Rotation is separate from addition to prevent recomputation. */
        private static void FF(ref uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d, uint x, int s, uint ac)
        {
            (a) += F((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (uint)(ac);
            (a) = ROTATE_LEFT((a), (s));
            (a) += (b);
        }
        private static void GG(ref uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d, uint x, int s, uint ac)
        {
            (a) += G((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (uint)(ac);
            (a) = ROTATE_LEFT((a), (s));
            (a) += (b);
        }
        private static void HH(ref uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d, uint x, int s, uint ac)
        {
            (a) += H((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (uint)(ac);
            (a) = ROTATE_LEFT((a), (s));
            (a) += (b);
        }
        private static void II(ref uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d, uint x, int s, uint ac)
        {
            (a) += I((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (uint)(ac);
            (a) = ROTATE_LEFT((a), (s));
            (a) += (b);
        }

        /* MD5 initialization. Begins an MD5 operation, writing a new context. */
        private static void MD5Init(MD5_CTX context)  /* context */
        {
            context.count[0] = context.count[1] = 0;

            /* Load magic initialization constants. */
            context.state[0] = 0x67452301;
            context.state[1] = 0xefcdab89;
            context.state[2] = 0x98badcfe;
            context.state[3] = 0x10325476;
        }

        /* MD5 block update operation. Continues an MD5 message-digest
           operation, processing another message block, and updating the
           context. */
        private static void MD5Update(MD5_CTX context,  /* context */
                                      byte[] input,     /* input block */
                                      uint inputIndex,  // Starting index for input block
                                      uint inputLen)    /* length of input block */
        {
            /* Compute number of bytes mod 64 */
            uint index = (uint)((context.count[0] >> 3) & 0x3F);

            /* Update number of bits */
            if ((context.count[0] += ((uint)inputLen << 3)) < ((uint)inputLen << 3))
            {
                context.count[1]++;
            }
            context.count[1] += ((uint)inputLen >> 29);

            uint partLen = 64 - index;

            /* Transform as many times as possible. */
            uint i = 0;
            if (inputLen >= partLen)
            {
                Buffer.BlockCopy(input, (int)inputIndex, context.buffer, (int)index, (int)partLen);
                MD5Transform(context.state, context.buffer, 0);

                for (i = partLen; i + 63 < inputLen; i += 64)
                {
                    MD5Transform(context.state, input, inputIndex + i);
                }

                index = 0;
            }

            /* Buffer remaining input */
            Buffer.BlockCopy(input, (int)(inputIndex + i), context.buffer, (int)index, (int)(inputLen - i));
        }

        /* MD5 finalization. Ends an MD5 message-digest operation, writing the
           the message digest and zeroizing the context. */
        private static void MD5Final(byte[] digest,    /* message digest */
                                     MD5_CTX context)  /* context */
        {
            byte[] bits = new byte[8];

            /* Save number of bits */
            Encode(bits, context.count, 8);

            /* Pad out to 56 mod 64. */
            uint index = (uint)((context.count[0] >> 3) & 0x3f);
            uint padLen = (index < 56) ? (56 - index) : (120 - index);
            MD5Update(context, PADDING, 0, padLen);

            /* Append length (before padding) */
            MD5Update(context, bits, 0, 8);

            /* Store state in digest */
            Encode(digest, context.state, 16);

            /* Zeroize sensitive information. */
            context.Clear();
        }

        /* MD5 basic transformation. Transforms state based on block. */
        private static void MD5Transform(uint[] state,
                                         byte[] block,
                                         uint blockIndex)
        {
            uint a = state[0], b = state[1], c = state[2], d = state[3];
            uint[] x = new uint[16];

            Decode(x, block, blockIndex, 64);

            /* Round 1 */
            FF(ref a, b, c, d, x[0], S11, 0xd76aa478); /* 1 */
            FF(ref d, a, b, c, x[1], S12, 0xe8c7b756); /* 2 */
            FF(ref c, d, a, b, x[2], S13, 0x242070db); /* 3 */
            FF(ref b, c, d, a, x[3], S14, 0xc1bdceee); /* 4 */
            FF(ref a, b, c, d, x[4], S11, 0xf57c0faf); /* 5 */
            FF(ref d, a, b, c, x[5], S12, 0x4787c62a); /* 6 */
            FF(ref c, d, a, b, x[6], S13, 0xa8304613); /* 7 */
            FF(ref b, c, d, a, x[7], S14, 0xfd469501); /* 8 */
            FF(ref a, b, c, d, x[8], S11, 0x698098d8); /* 9 */
            FF(ref d, a, b, c, x[9], S12, 0x8b44f7af); /* 10 */
            FF(ref c, d, a, b, x[10], S13, 0xffff5bb1); /* 11 */
            FF(ref b, c, d, a, x[11], S14, 0x895cd7be); /* 12 */
            FF(ref a, b, c, d, x[12], S11, 0x6b901122); /* 13 */
            FF(ref d, a, b, c, x[13], S12, 0xfd987193); /* 14 */
            FF(ref c, d, a, b, x[14], S13, 0xa679438e); /* 15 */
            FF(ref b, c, d, a, x[15], S14, 0x49b40821); /* 16 */

            /* Round 2 */
            GG(ref a, b, c, d, x[1], S21, 0xf61e2562); /* 17 */
            GG(ref d, a, b, c, x[6], S22, 0xc040b340); /* 18 */
            GG(ref c, d, a, b, x[11], S23, 0x265e5a51); /* 19 */
            GG(ref b, c, d, a, x[0], S24, 0xe9b6c7aa); /* 20 */
            GG(ref a, b, c, d, x[5], S21, 0xd62f105d); /* 21 */
            GG(ref d, a, b, c, x[10], S22, 0x02441453); /* 22 */
            GG(ref c, d, a, b, x[15], S23, 0xd8a1e681); /* 23 */
            GG(ref b, c, d, a, x[4], S24, 0xe7d3fbc8); /* 24 */
            GG(ref a, b, c, d, x[9], S21, 0x21e1cde6); /* 25 */
            GG(ref d, a, b, c, x[14], S22, 0xc33707d6); /* 26 */
            GG(ref c, d, a, b, x[3], S23, 0xf4d50d87); /* 27 */
            GG(ref b, c, d, a, x[8], S24, 0x455a14ed); /* 28 */
            GG(ref a, b, c, d, x[13], S21, 0xa9e3e905); /* 29 */
            GG(ref d, a, b, c, x[2], S22, 0xfcefa3f8); /* 30 */
            GG(ref c, d, a, b, x[7], S23, 0x676f02d9); /* 31 */
            GG(ref b, c, d, a, x[12], S24, 0x8d2a4c8a); /* 32 */

            /* Round 3 */
            HH(ref a, b, c, d, x[5], S31, 0xfffa3942); /* 33 */
            HH(ref d, a, b, c, x[8], S32, 0x8771f681); /* 34 */
            HH(ref c, d, a, b, x[11], S33, 0x6d9d6122); /* 35 */
            HH(ref b, c, d, a, x[14], S34, 0xfde5380c); /* 36 */
            HH(ref a, b, c, d, x[1], S31, 0xa4beea44); /* 37 */
            HH(ref d, a, b, c, x[4], S32, 0x4bdecfa9); /* 38 */
            HH(ref c, d, a, b, x[7], S33, 0xf6bb4b60); /* 39 */
            HH(ref b, c, d, a, x[10], S34, 0xbebfbc70); /* 40 */
            HH(ref a, b, c, d, x[13], S31, 0x289b7ec6); /* 41 */
            HH(ref d, a, b, c, x[0], S32, 0xeaa127fa); /* 42 */
            HH(ref c, d, a, b, x[3], S33, 0xd4ef3085); /* 43 */
            HH(ref b, c, d, a, x[6], S34, 0x04881d05); /* 44 */
            HH(ref a, b, c, d, x[9], S31, 0xd9d4d039); /* 45 */
            HH(ref d, a, b, c, x[12], S32, 0xe6db99e5); /* 46 */
            HH(ref c, d, a, b, x[15], S33, 0x1fa27cf8); /* 47 */
            HH(ref b, c, d, a, x[2], S34, 0xc4ac5665); /* 48 */

            /* Round 4 */
            II(ref a, b, c, d, x[0], S41, 0xf4292244); /* 49 */
            II(ref d, a, b, c, x[7], S42, 0x432aff97); /* 50 */
            II(ref c, d, a, b, x[14], S43, 0xab9423a7); /* 51 */
            II(ref b, c, d, a, x[5], S44, 0xfc93a039); /* 52 */
            II(ref a, b, c, d, x[12], S41, 0x655b59c3); /* 53 */
            II(ref d, a, b, c, x[3], S42, 0x8f0ccc92); /* 54 */
            II(ref c, d, a, b, x[10], S43, 0xffeff47d); /* 55 */
            II(ref b, c, d, a, x[1], S44, 0x85845dd1); /* 56 */
            II(ref a, b, c, d, x[8], S41, 0x6fa87e4f); /* 57 */
            II(ref d, a, b, c, x[15], S42, 0xfe2ce6e0); /* 58 */
            II(ref c, d, a, b, x[6], S43, 0xa3014314); /* 59 */
            II(ref b, c, d, a, x[13], S44, 0x4e0811a1); /* 60 */
            II(ref a, b, c, d, x[4], S41, 0xf7537e82); /* 61 */
            II(ref d, a, b, c, x[11], S42, 0xbd3af235); /* 62 */
            II(ref c, d, a, b, x[2], S43, 0x2ad7d2bb); /* 63 */
            II(ref b, c, d, a, x[9], S44, 0xeb86d391); /* 64 */

            state[0] += a;
            state[1] += b;
            state[2] += c;
            state[3] += d;

            /* Zeroize sensitive information. */
            Array.Clear(x, 0, x.Length);
        }

        /* Encodes input (UINT4) into output (unsigned char). Assumes len is
           a multiple of 4. */
        private static void Encode(byte[] output,
                                   uint[] input,
                                   uint len)
        {
            for (uint i = 0, j = 0; j < len; i++, j += 4)
            {
                output[j] = (byte)(input[i] & 0xff);
                output[j + 1] = (byte)((input[i] >> 8) & 0xff);
                output[j + 2] = (byte)((input[i] >> 16) & 0xff);
                output[j + 3] = (byte)((input[i] >> 24) & 0xff);
            }
        }

        /* Decodes input (unsigned char) into output (UINT4). Assumes len is
           a multiple of 4. */
        private static void Decode(uint[] output,
                                   byte[] input,
                                   uint inputIndex,
                                   uint len)
        {
            for (uint i = 0, j = 0; j < len; i++, j += 4)
            {
                output[i] = ((uint)input[inputIndex + j]) |
                    (((uint)input[inputIndex + j + 1]) << 8) |
                    (((uint)input[inputIndex + j + 2]) << 16) |
                    (((uint)input[inputIndex + j + 3]) << 24);
            }
        }

        public object GetState()
        {
            return new StateSerialize
            {
                state = _context.state.Clone() as uint[],
                count = _context.count.Clone() as uint[],
                buffer = _context.buffer.Clone() as byte[]
            };
        }

        public void LoadState(object state)
        {
            var s = state as StateSerialize;
            Array.Copy(s.buffer, _context.buffer, _context.buffer.Length);
            Array.Copy(s.count, _context.count, _context.count.Length);
            Array.Copy(s.state, _context.state, _context.state.Length);
        }

        [Serializable]
        class StateSerialize
        {
            public uint[] state { get; set; }
            public uint[] count { get; set; }
            public byte[] buffer { get; set; }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/ Crypto library (there also nuget package), they have MD5 implementation, but hold the state in private fields, however its relatively easy to get/set it with the following code

```
public class MD5State
{
    public uint H1, H2, H3, H4;
    public uint[] X;
    public int xOff;
    public long byteCount;
    public byte[] xBuf;
    public int xBufOff;
}
public class MD5WithState : MD5Digest
{
    public MD5State State
    {
        get
        {
            var rv = (MD5State)CopyFields(GetType().BaseType, typeof(MD5State), this, new MD5State());
            return (MD5State)CopyFields(GetType().BaseType.BaseType, typeof(MD5State), this, rv); 
        }
        set
        {
            CopyFields(typeof(MD5State), GetType().BaseType, value, this);
            CopyFields(typeof(MD5State), GetType().BaseType.BaseType, value, this);
        }
    }
    protected object CopyFields(Type srcType, Type trgType, object src, object trg)
    {
        var targetProps = trgType.GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        var sourceProps = srcType.GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var p1 in targetProps)
        {
            var p2 = sourceProps.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == p1.Name);
            if (p2 != null)
            {
                p1.SetValue(trg, p2.GetValue(src));
            }
        }
        return trg;
    }
}
```

Btw. Measured performance for 3.5Gb file for different MD5 implementations, here is the result:

```
Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.MD5Digest hash: c4a6790f0c511594880ae74445943626, elapsed: 00:00:18.2459386
SInnovations.Azure.Storage.MD5.MD5Managed hash: c4a6790f0c511594880ae74445943626, elapsed: 00:00:33.2032547
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 Block hash: c4a6790f0c511594880ae74445943626, elapsed: 00:00:08.2592109
```